# Подскажите библиотеки для работы с I2C для Windows

Tags: windows, железо, драйвер, поиск-библиотек

Не могу найти готовые библиотеки для работы с устройством I2C для операционной системы Windows.
Нужно настраивать регистры устройства из моей программы.
Нужно что-то типа функции
`i2c_write(<адрес устройства на шине I2C>, <регистр>, <значение>)`.
Для Windows.

Comment: Может на Github пошерстить решения, например, на том же Python?

Comment: Может быть, я не до конца понимаю суть технологии I2C. Появилась идея, что с устройством I2C в Windows нужно работать через COM-порт (физически это будет эмуляция COM-порта). В записью в COM-порт проблем нет. Буду пробовать.

Comment: I2C и UART— даже физически совершенно два разных интерфейса.